# PyZDDE - get ray trace information in global coordinates

Tags: python

I have successfully traced a ray in Zemax using pyzdde. (using zGetTrace) However I need the information in global coordinates as opposed to local. is there a way to get that? Thanks.

-T

edit:

Here is the test code. The ray object returns the ray information in correct local coordinates. I need it in global. Basically the same effect when one checks the "global coordinate" box in the Zemax ray trace window.

```python
import sys
import pyzdde.zdde as pyz

ln = pyz.createLink()

path = 'C:\\'
filename = 'myZemaxFile.zmx'
fullpath = path + filename
ln.zLoadFile(fullpath)
hx = 0.0; hy = 0
px = 0.0; py = 0.0
wave = 1;surf = 4
mode = 0
# mode 0 = real
ray = ln.zGetTrace(wave,mode,surf,hx,hy,px,py)

# close the communication channel 
pyz.closeLink()
```

Comment: Sure. Please show what you have so far, and someone may come along and point to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are several ways of handling this (depending on the type of lens design).

For example, you could use the operand 'GLCZ' (Global vertex z-coordinate of the surface defined by Surf) in the following way to get the z-coordinate of the image surface (or the surface of interest) in the global coordinates:

```
ln.zGetUpdate() # may not be required
image_surf = ln.zGetNumSurf() # assuming last surface as the image surf
image_z = ln.zOperandValue('GLCZ', image_surf)
```

Once you have `image_z`, then the tuple `(ray.x, ray.y, image_z)` represents the x, y, z coordinates of the ray intersection with the image surface.

I hope that helps.

### UPDATE:

A simpler option (without even doing ray tracing) is to use the operands `RAGX`, `RAGY`, and `RAGZ` (as pointed out by Todd B). They directly give the global coordinates of the ray intersections. For example:

```
ln.zGetUpdate() # may not be required
surf = ln.zGetNumSurf() # assuming last surface as the image surf
wave, hx, hy, px, py = 1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
rayInterceptX = ln.zOperandValue('RAGX', surf, wave, hx, hy, px, py)
rayInterceptY = ln.zOperandValue('RAGY', surf, wave, hx, hy, px, py)
rayInterceptZ = ln.zOperandValue('RAGZ', surf, wave, hx, hy, px, py)
```

Comment: Thanks. That definitely lead me in the right direction. The operand that works for my application is 'RAGX', 'RAGY', and 'RAGZ'. I also found another way but it is unnecessarily complicated. I was able to get the global rotation matrix (zGetGlobalMatrix) and apply the transformation to local coordinates. Again, unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: The operands 'RAGX', 'RAGY' and 'RAGZ' are definitely the simplest (and probably the best) way to get the global coordinates of the ray. Somehow, I didn't remember them when I wrote my answer first.